# Why do I get java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.amazonaws.auth.AWSCredentials error?

Tags: java, maven, jakarta-ee, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have included the dependency from Maven, yet I see this error:

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.amazonaws.auth.AWSCredentials

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
    <artifactId>aws-java-sdk</artifactId>
    <version>1.8.5</version>
</dependency>
```

Follwoing is the code that I am using and the method that I would like to call. It runs perfectly when called from a main method, but fails when called from a request.

public class ThumbnailProcessor {

```
    public static String processThumbnail(String link, String keyName , String secret ) {

        AmazonS3 s3Client = null;
        link = StringUtils.removeEnd(link, "/");
        int index = link.lastIndexOf("/");
        String fileName = StringUtils.substring(link, index + 1, link.length());
        String existingBucketName = "staticmedia";
            String fileNameWithoutExt = StringUtils.substringBefore(fileName, ".");
        String ext = StringUtils.substringAfter(fileName, ".");
        InitiateMultipartUploadResult initResponse = null;
        String randomname = null;
        try {
            URL url = new URL(link);
            BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(url);
            image = Thumbnails.of(image).forceSize(150, 100).asBufferedImage();
            randomname = String.format("%s.%s",
                    RandomStringUtils.randomAlphanumeric(8), ext);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(randomname);
            sb.insert(0, fileNameWithoutExt + "_");
            randomname = sb.toString();
            ImageIO.write(image, "jpg", new File("src/main/java/" + randomname));
            String filePath = "src/main/java/" + randomname;
            AWSCredentials awsCredentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(keyName,
                    secret);
            s3Client = new AmazonS3Client(awsCredentials);
            InitiateMultipartUploadRequest initRequest = new InitiateMultipartUploadRequest(
                    existingBucketName, randomname);
            initResponse = s3Client.initiateMultipartUpload(initRequest);
            File file = new File(filePath);

            PutObjectResult item = s3Client.putObject(new PutObjectRequest(
                    existingBucketName, randomname, file));
            return "https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/"
                    + randomname;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            s3Client.abortMultipartUpload(new AbortMultipartUploadRequest(
                    existingBucketName, randomname, initResponse.getUploadId()));
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Where are you getting this error exactly?

Comment: When I try to call the class that has this

Comment: I have a class and I am making a static call to it ThumbnailProcessor.processThumbnail(); The ThumbnailProcessor has the reference to AWSCredentials

Comment: You need to provide the code where this is happening.

Comment: in your IDE, do you see the jar added in build path? Try to update/refresh your project.

Comment: Yes I see it. I am wondering if I have conflicting dependencies.